# jQuery Ajax call to spring controller return in error method while controller getting the correct data

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

I have a jQuery ajax call as:

```
  $("tr." + trClassName).each(function() {                
     list1.push(some Id from td);
     list2.push(some id from another td);
});
```

// here **list1** and **list2** is like {1,2,3,4,...}

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : "./bulkUpdate" ,
    data : "id=" + id + "&list1=" +list1+ "&list2=" + list2,
    success : function(response) {
        alert("Dispaly orders updated successfully");
    },
    error : function(e) {
        alert('Error: ' + e);
    }
});
```

Now in controller i have the receiver code as:

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/bulkUpdate", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public @ResponseBody String updateOrders(@ModelAttribute(value = "content") Content content) {

       // **Content** class has attributes for **list1** and **list2**
       // here i am getting the correct data like:

       List<String> list1= content.getList1();
       List<String> list2= content.getList2();

       /* do something */

       return "success";
    }
```

All things are running ok, but it always returns to

```
error : function(e) {
    alert('Error: ' + e);
}
```

In fire bug i am getting the error as:

```
*"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/web-pack/tool/languageTool/bulkUpdate?id=1&list1=8,9,10,11,13,105,129,132,12,135,134&list2=8,9,10,11,14,15,16,17,18,19,20*
```

Comment: how you make sure that controller completes the request successfully? and I believe you are sending `list1` and `list2` as `String` not as `List<String>`

Comment: @GGG I am debugging the code and its giving the correct value in controller. Please see the code in controller in my new answer section

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> List2= content.getList2();
int counter = 0;
for (String id1: content.getList1()) {

  sysout(id1 + List2.get(counter));
  counter ++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you got your success.jsp view created and good loaded by your ViewResolver?

I think you are confusing, if you only want to response "success" string use HttpServletResponse.getWriter() to do directly.

Comment: i forgot to add @ResponseBody tag in the return type of controller, which works as same HttpServletResponse.getWriter()... thnaks for the correct point, just a small mistake made it.. thnaks a lot